# Show legends as x axis labels of bar charts in plotly python

Tags: python, charts, plotly, visualization

I am working on a group bar chart in plotly where I have mapped multiple rows in bar chart. Here is the code explaining what I did:

```
data = [{"Project":"Project A","Features":{"AC":95,"Elec":130, "Area":2349.46, "Cars":30, "Rent":2345.00},"ScaledFeatures":{"AC":95,"Elec":130, "Area":2349.46, "Cars":30, "Rent":2345.00}},
{"Project":"Project B","Features":{"AC":95,"Elec":130, "Area":2120.00, "Cars":42, "Rent":5432},"ScaledFeatures":{"AC":95,"Elec":130, "Area":2120.00, "Cars":42, "Rent":2345}}
       ]
featureKeys = list(data[0]["Features"].keys())

for key in featureKeys:
    featureData = ([d["ScaledFeatures"][key] for d in data])
    minimumFeatureValue = min(featureData)
    for d in data:
        d["ScaledFeatures"][key] = d["ScaledFeatures"][key]/minimumFeatureValue

barData = []
for d in data:
    barData.append(go.Bar(name=d['Project'], x=featureKeys, y=list(d["ScaledFeatures"].values()),text=list(d["Features"].values()),textposition='auto'))

# set plot layout  
layout = go.Layout(
    xaxis={"mirror" : "allticks", 'side': 'top'} # x-axis also at top
)

fig = go.Figure(data=barData,layout=layout)

# Change the bar mode
#fig.update_traces(textposition='outside')
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

Here is the output it generates:

[image: Current Output]

I want to generate the following like output from this where legends are coming in x-axis:

[image: Required Output]

What I have done till now is to use multiple axes but that draws its own bars n the same chart. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could use multicategory x axes here, as in [this example](https://plot.ly/python/axes/#subcategory-multicategory-axes). However you would have A/B and AC/Elec etc. together on the same side. If you don't want to use this you can use annotations https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/#simple-annotation. Also, here you could consider using `px.bar` from `plotly.express`: https://plot.ly/python/bar-charts/